# Get server root directory

Tags: php

I am running this code to read a directory (on Apache server):

```
$mydir = '/media/video/';

$root_dir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];

if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'localhost') === false){
    $dir = $root_dir . $mydir;
}else{
    $dir = $mydir;
}
```

There have been some server configuration changes recently and now it returns this:

```
/home2/interact/public_html
```

Is there a rmore reliable way to always get corrent root path?

I need a public_html path.

Comment: Test `dirname ( __FILE__ )`

Comment: Now I am getting: 'home/interact/public_html/tst/op'. op is my working directory. How can I know that '/home2/interact/public_html' is actually root in this case?

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` to better fetched the way you did, there is another option ie. parsing the apache configuration file, it mentioned here (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-find-unix-linux-apache-documentroot/) this might not be good idea because it can be possible that someone has modified the configuration but server is yet to load it, in such cases it will lead to wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

// split url path on '/' slash characher and save result in $urlParts(array). check if $urlParts array contains public_html. it means /home2/interact/public_html is root.

$dirPath = dirname ( **FILE** );

$urlParts = explode('/', $dirPath);

if(in_array('public_html', $urlParts)) {

```
//do something
```

}